# How I can read this in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Can anyone tell me how to read this piece of Code?

```
[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<IPv4> {
      return this;
  }
```

Comment: You are looking at a property that defines how the object can be used as an iterator (used in for loops, etc).  Each element in the loop is an IPv4 type.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator

Comment: geekabyte.io/2019/06/symbols-in-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

That signature allows you to make you object iterable on a `for..of` loop or a spread operation. Here is an example:

```js
class MyIterable<T> {
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T> { // This "T"
    return [][Symbol.iterator]();
  }
}

const iterator = new MyIterable<string>(); // Which in this case is "string"

for (const foo of iterator) { // Defines the type of "foo" here

  // Do something with a foo of type T ("string")

}
```